# What’s on Ronan’s chest whilst he inserts the Infinity Stone?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, guardians-of-the-galaxy-1, guardians-of-the-galaxy

Does a Japanese or Chinese symbol appear on Ronan's chest after he takes the Infinity Stone out of the orb in the *Guardians of The Galaxy* film? If so, what does it mean?

[image]

Comment: It may be useful to add an image or the video of this scene: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RTTSQnGn_Ic#t=00m42s

Comment: Doesn't look like a Japanese or Chinese character to me at least (the bottom half in particular I'm pretty sure I've never seen in any kanji). My guess would be that it's not meant to look like anything in particular.

Answer (score 18):

It appears that the purple lines are following the lines in Ronan's armor, which is consistent with the "glowing from within" visual used anytime someone touches the infinity stone.

[image: Comparison images of Ronan's armor with Kanji-esque lines drawn in on the right]

While these lines do superficially resemble some sort of Kanji or Japanese character, there's no evidence it actually represents one.

[image: Kanji with some superficial resemblance to the glowing lines]

Comment: Just curious? what would be the purpose of having the kanji `天` on his chest?

Comment: Just illustrating the resemblance.

Comment: Resemblance to what?

Comment: I must have missread your previous comment. Missed "on his chest". I don't know of any purpose, other than perhaps a directors in-joke.

Comment: . Oh,  I see now.

Answer (score 12):

If you were really trying to see a Japanese /Chinese Kanji in this I would the top resembles `士 = Shi` which does hold the meaning of "Samurai", but can also be written as `侍 = Samurai`.

[image]

[image]

[The meaning of `士`](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E5%A3%AB)

It is also a key Kanji in the word `武士 = bushi`  or "Warrior" in English.

[image]

How ever , the bottom half of the image you provided of Ronan is gibberish and resembles nothing.

So, the makers could have deliberately put in this to resemble Kanji and as the top half does very much resemble a Kanji that is used for "Warrior" which also holds a meaning of "Samurai" which in its-self implicitly means "Warrior" here in Japan. The fact that Ronan is a warrior could point to the makers doing this on purpose.

Source: Educated in Japan.

Comment: Also, a "ronin" is a wandering samurai without a master. Ronan has taken it upon himself to wage war against the Nova Corps, even though the Kree empire (his former masters) have negotiated peace. Could have been intended along those lines.

Comment: @DCShannon, I was no sure if that is were his name comes from, so I did not include that, but you are absolutely correct and written　‘浪人` in Kanji

Comment: Ronan is also an Irish name, meaning "little-seal". I do like the idea of the the Japanese influence, but it seems like the director/writer would have put in more than just these two elements. http://www.behindthename.com/name/ro10na10n